# MS Access query: can't filter data using a criteria expression from a combo box

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I have a table with data. Each record has dates and other data.
I build a query to let user filter by time-period. In the query I use DataPart() in separate columns of the query just to segregate year ("YYYY") and month ("m") from the date of interest.
I have a form with two combos: one with a list of years (e.g. 2020, 2021...) and the another one with a list of months (e.g. 1,2,3...)
Everything works smoothly unless I select "Q1" in the combo (related to this string: 1 or 2 or 3 ,for example) that would end in an empty query. If I write 1 or 2 or 3 directly in the query criteria it works perfectly. Of course, if I write the same criteria with quotation marks ("1 or 2 or 3") it will fail the same way.

I tried hundreds of different ways to solve this, but I can't find a solution. Even with an IIF statement in the query criteria (e.g. IIF combo is Q1 then 1 or 2 or 3) won't work: whatever I write there different from a number will fail.
I think that I am stuck with a dumb problem, sort of type mismatch, but unfortunately can't work it out.
Every suggestion will be really appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that unless you use VBA to rewrite the *SQL* like this if the combobox returns "1, 2, 3":

```vb
SQL = "Select * From Table Where DatePart('m', [DateField]) In (" & [YourMonthComboBox] & ")"
```

Or, here the *RowSource*, split the value returned from the combobox if it can return, say, "M1", "M2", or "Q1" into its parts - for Q1, "Q" and "1":

```sql
Select * From Table Where DatePart(Mid([YourMonthComboBox], 1, 1), [DateField]) = Mid([YourMonthComboBox], 2)
```

Comment: Your splitting suggestion worked perfectly! I use first char from first column of "CHOOSE THE PERIOD" combobox:
`"m1";"GENNAIO";"m3";"MARZO";"m6";"GIUGNO";"q3";"Q3";"y";"ANNO"` 
 (incomplete list, just for testing purposes)
to set the query's field expression DatePart argument ("m" for month, "q" for quarter and "yyyy" for the year) and then I use the following character to form the query's criteria. If "y", I need 4 chars to match, so I use data from the combobox CHOOSE YEAR. This way, I am able to filter all table's records by month, quarter or the whole year. Thank you very much!